# Ionic 4 + horizontal scroll + ion-split-pane causes error on Angular Material's drag and drop

Tags: scroll, drag-and-drop, ionic4, angular-material-7

In my Ionic 4 app there's an ion-split-pane. Inside the ion-split-pane there's a ion-router-outlet where goes my ionic page.

Inside the page we are trying to implement a kanban with columns. We are trying to implement the capacity to move itens among columns using drag and drop.

But when there is horizontal scroll, in the place where the columns are inside, we cannot drop the itens.

We are using Angular Material's drag and drop.

How can we implement a drag and drop inside a scrollpane in a ionic split pane?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in GitHub I could find you 2 sample projects that make a simple Kanban Board with Angular 7 + MD Controls ;)

1-) [GitHub - Kanban Board](https://github.com/1antares1/Kanban_Angular) (works!)
**Screenshot:**
[image]

2-) [GitHub - kanban](https://github.com/davidalisson/kanban)

These may not use the native components of Ionic, but the logic is the same: Only the controls vary from one another.

Check out the source and I hope you find it useful. ;)

**Best regards.**

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is related/caused by ion-router-outlet. By replacing it with router-outlet the drag and drop started to work.